# Command Line argument in C not printing correctly

Tags: c, command-line, arguments

im trying to test how my program is receiving a users command line input:

my command line input to test is:

```
"./concordance 15 < input.txt"
```

the rest of the program works but to test the arguments. so in my main function i have this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);          //runs through command line for arg
    }
    printf("%d\n", argc);                 //prints total arguments
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I enter my command line, the program prints:

```
./concordance
15
2
```

for my program to work I need to open the input.txt file so my question is, why is the program only printing "./concordance", and "15" aswell as only seeing 2 arguments if I have "<" and "input.txt" in the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the command line and "stdin" - "15" is a command line argument. The shell sees the '<' and "redirects" the file to your program on it's `stdin` stream.

If you don't want to use stdin to process the file, just pass it's name and open yourself: `./concordance 15 input.txt` (argv[2] will be input.txt)

Comment: oh so i should use stdin to then open the file? sorry im somewhat new to c

Comment: If you use `<` the file already "is" stdin. If you use `scanf` etc it will read from your file and not the keyboard. Without a bit more context on what you are doing it is hard to tell whether using stdin or an explicit file is better (gut tells me explicit file...)

Comment: ohhhhh okay wow that makes total sense now thanks. yea its basically taking a text file with a bunch of strings and outputting a concordance  of them.

Comment: Based on that I think a file would make more sense than trying to use stdin. There are plenty of C file IO examples out there.

Answer (score 1):

`<` is not interpreted as a command line argument but is instead interpreted by the shell to redirect standard input to be the specified file instead of the parent standard input, typically the shell.